# Updating Event Details using Eventrite API v3

Tags: api, eventbrite

I'm trying to edit Eventbrite event using version 3 of the API but I always returns false.

```
 $request_url = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/xxxxxx';

 $options = array(
     'http' => array(
     'method' => 'POST',
     'header'=> "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxx"
     ),
     'name' => array(
        'text'=>'Hi',
        'html'=>'<p>Hi</p>'
    ));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $options);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $json_data = curl_exec($ch);
    $resp_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($json_data);
```

This always returns me :

```
   boolean false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an options array with curl as you are setting those options in `curl_setopt`. Just make a data array and submit it.

```
<?php
$request_url = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/xxxxxx';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'name' => array(
        'text'=>'Hi',
        'html'=>'<p>Hi</p>'
    )
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$json_data = curl_exec($ch);
$resp_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($json_data);
```

Though according to the [docs](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/formats/event/#ebapi-std:format-event) there is a minimum amount of data to create an event.